# How to handle system.exit in the cucumber test case

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testcase

newbie to cucumber and selenuim in java

I am calling a method in cucumber test case and there if it goes into the else part it would send a mail and exit from the system.when i am running this method with cucumber then it will send the mail and exit with test case.
How to resolve that

and after that by using selenium i want to open the browser and check the mailbox to check the mail has sent by the code or not.

Comment: call the method (selenium) to check the mail before the exit is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);`

When you invoke this method, the thread `hook` will be called whenever the VM wants to shutdown (including when a `System.exit()` is called). You can add all your validation in the `hook` thread.

Check the  [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) for more information about shutdown hook.

Answer (score 0):

call the method (selenium)  before the exit

```
else{
    //code to send the mail
     seleniumMethod();
    System.exit();
 }
seleniumMethod(){
```

//check mail
    }